# How to limit drop down menu within a time interval using Angular.js and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs

I need one help.I need to active one drop down menu for `2` days then after 2 days it will not display to the user using PHP and Angular.js. I am explaining my code below.

```
<tr ng-repeat="p in listOfProductData">
  <td>
       <select class="form-control"  id="status" ng-model="order_status" ng-change="changeOrderStatus(order_id,shipping_email,p.pro_data_id,order_status)">
          <option value="">Select Status</option>
          <option value="Ordered">ORDERED</option>
          <option value="InProgress">IN-PROGRESS</option>
          <option value="Shipped">SHIPPED</option>
          <option value="Delivered">DELIVERED</option>
          <option value="Canceled">CANCELED</option>
          <option value="Return">RETURN</option>
       </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

In the above select menu i have one `RETURN` option i need to active it for 2 days according to the datetime saved in my database.I am explaining my table below.

> db_time:

```
id   cur_time

1    2016-03-16 14:33:19
```

at each page reload it will check the this time in database if it 2 days is already gone the return option will not display to user.`listOfProductData` will contain the value from `db_time` table.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

After check db_time use `data-ng-show` to show and hide menu for users.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php
$db_date = "2016-03-16 14:33:19";

$curr_date=date_create(date("Y-m-d"));

$diff=date_diff($curr_date, $db_date);
$days = $diff->format("%a");
if($days <= 2) {?>
    <select class="form-control"  id="status" ng-model="order_status" ng-change="changeOrderStatus(order_id,shipping_email,p.pro_data_id,order_status)">
         <option value="">Select Status</option>
         <option value="Ordered">ORDERED</option>
         <option value="InProgress">IN-PROGRESS</option>
         <option value="Shipped">SHIPPED</option>
         <option value="Delivered">DELIVERED</option>
         <option value="Canceled">CANCELED</option>
         <option value="Return">RETURN</option>
    </select>
<?php
}
?>
```